How should I write the code if all the URLs are the same?
I'm trying to collect information about athletes from this site:
https://olympics.com/en/paris-2024/athletes. The total number of pages is 223, and each page contains information about 50 athletes.
I have written code to collect information about the 50 athletes on the 1st page, and I’ve successfully tested it. Now, I’d like to write code to collect information about athletes from the nth page to the (n+x)th page. However, the URL for every page is the same, so I can't figure out the solution.
Here is the code I mentioned above.
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

# Chrome Driver setup
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://olympics.com/en/paris-2024/athletes")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Click the cookies acceptance button
try:
    cookies_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
    )
    cookies_btn.click()
    print("Cookies accepted.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to accept cookies:", str(e))

time.sleep(3)

print("All athlete cards have been loaded successfully.")

# Create a blank list to collect information for each athlete
athletes_data = []

# Loop to collect information for each athlete
for i in range(1, 51):  # Loop for 50 athletes
    try:
        # Locate the athlete card
        athlete_card_xpath = f"//table[@id='mirs-table-athletes']//tr[{i}]//td[1]//a"
        athlete_card = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, athlete_card_xpath))
        )
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", athlete_card)
        time.sleep(1)

        # Click on the athlete card
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", athlete_card)

        # Collect athlete information
        name = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='PersonInfo']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/b"))
        ).text
        nationality = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='PersonInfo']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div"))
        ).text
        discipline = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='PersonInfo']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/span"))
        ).text
        age = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='PersonInfo']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]"))
        ).text.replace("Age:", "")
        gender = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='PersonInfo']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]"))
        ).text.replace("Gender:", "")

        # Additional fields (rank, medal, debut, occupation)
        rank = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mirs-table-biomedals']/tbody/tr/td[3]"))
        ).text if WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mirs-table-biomedals']/tbody/tr/td[3]"))) else None
        
        medal = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mirs-table-biomedals']/tbody/tr/td[4]/svg/use"))
        ).get_attribute("xlink:href") if WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mirs-table-biomedals']/tbody/tr/td[4]/svg/use"))) else None
        
        debut = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='BiographicalInformation']/div[2]/div[10]/p[2]"))
        ).text if WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='BiographicalInformation']/div[2]/div[10]/p[2]"))) else None
        
        occupation = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='BiographicalInformation']/div[2]/div[16]/p[2]"))
        ).text if WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='BiographicalInformation']/div[2]/div[16]/p[2]"))) else None

        # Add collected data to the list
        athletes_data.append([name, nationality, discipline, age, gender, rank, medal, debut, occupation])

        # Return to the list page
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.back()
        time.sleep(5)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to collect information for athlete {i}: {str(e)}")
        driver.back()
        time.sleep(3)

# Quit the browser
driver.quit()

# Create a DataFrame with the collected data
df = pd.DataFrame(athletes_data, columns=["Name", "Nationality", "Discipline", "Age", "Gender", "Rank", "Medal", "Debut", "Occupation"])

# Save to Excel file
df.to_excel("athletes_data.xlsx", index=False)
print("Athlete information has been saved to the file athletes_data.xlsx.")


you can get all the athletes from the API.

since you are using selenium why not click on next button to get list of next page, repeat the same till last page

I second @NikhilChauhan's point. The next button has the property aria-label="next page". This answer shows how to find the button using this label.

Once you've processed the first page you can locate the "next page" button then click it for as long as it is not disabled.
Here's a simplification of your code that will emit all athlete names:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

URL = "https://olympics.com/en/paris-2024/athletes"

BUTTON_SELECTOR = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='next page']"
SPAN_SELECTOR = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.competitor-long-name"
ONETRUST_SELECTOR = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#onetrust-reject-all-handler"
SCRIPT = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(); arguments[0].click();"


with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(URL)
    try:
        driver.find_element(*ONETRUST_SELECTOR).click()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    while True:
        try:
            for span in driver.find_elements(*SPAN_SELECTOR):
                print(span.text)
            button = driver.find_element(*BUTTON_SELECTOR)
            if button.get_attribute("disabled") is not None:
                break
            driver.execute_script(SCRIPT, button)
        except Exception as e:
            break


Thank you very much for every expert's answer. I'll try it and come back.
